# FinancialData returns a Failure[] object

Tags: finance, error-trapping

What is the recommended way to deal with this (basically, if I get "Failure", I would like to say that the data is missing, and I can obviously call the function inside another function, check if the head is "Failure", and then do something, but there has to be a clean way to deal with it, or at least I hope there is...

Comment: Are you looking  for `FailureQ`? You should be aware that data functions usually return `Missing[...]` when data is missing, `Failure[...]` would rather be returned when something else fails, e.g. when a network connection to the WRI servers can't be established or times out.

Comment: Thanks! In my setting, I am looking at historical data, and it fails when it can't find the symbol, so it definitely returns `Failure[]`

Comment: Interesting, for me a call to `FinancialData` with a symbol which does not exist gives a message and returns unevaluated (e.g. `FinancialData["dosenotexist"]`). Which version are you using? Can you give a specific example? An invalid call (nonexisting symbol) might of course also be defined to be a `Failure`. I get `Missing` when asking for data for an existing symbol for a certain date for which no data is available (e.g. `FinancialData["GE", {{1800, 1, 1}}]`). I'm not sure how strict WRI is in sticking to their own conventions and which corner cases they will treat which way...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I am trying to isolate the phenomenon (I was running this on a very large dataset).